# When should I use diagnostic_aggregator?

Tags: ros, diagnostics, diagnostic-aggregator, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please help in writing up a ROS best practice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11844/when-should-i-use-diagnostic_aggregator?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Executive Summary**

Use `/diagnostics` to publish hardware diagnostics data from **every** device driver.

Use `diagnostics_aggregator` to collect and group diagnostics data on any significant system.

**Background: /diagnostics**

To begin with, it is best practice to set up diagnostics on all robot hardware at a minimum.  Most of the drivers included with ROS include some form of diagnostics messages.  The ROS diagnostics toolchain is not a computation graph level concept (like parameters, nodes, or topics), but is instead built on top of the `/diagnostics` topic.

Hardware drivers publish to the `/diagnostics` topic a [diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_msgs/html/msg/DiagnosticArray.html) message, which contains a header (sequence number, timestamp, and frame_id) and an array of [diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticStatus](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_msgs/html/msg/DiagnosticStatus.html) messages.

The `DiagnosticStatus` contains:

- `byte level` - One of three states (OK, WARN, ERROR), which represents the overall hardware health.
- `string name` - The name of the device this `DiagnosticStatus` represents
- `string hardware_id` - A unique hardware identifier, possibly a serial number or UUID
- [diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue[]](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_msgs/html/msg/KeyValue.html) - An array of key/value pairs used to represent any additional pertinent information about the sensor. (For example "temperature":"35C", "frequency:100Hz", "voltage:24V")

Any node subscribing to this `/diagnostics` topic will receive the raw diagnostics messages (which can be overwhelming on a large system like the PR2).

To visualize raw diagnostics messages in ROS, you can currently use the [runtime_monitor](http://ros.org/wiki/runtime_monitor) by simply running:

```
rosrun runtime_monitor montior
```

**More Background: The diagnostic_updater**

The [diagnostic_updater](http://ros.org/wiki/diagnostic_updater) is not quite relevant to the aggregator, but is an often-overlooked tool.  It provides convenience functions for working with the `DiagnosticArray` messages with your hardware drivers in C++.

With the `diagnostic_updater` libraries, you can create an object for interacting with `DiagnosticArray` messgaes, as well as monitoring frequency status, and over/under monitoring for critical values in your hardware device (temperature, voltage, etc).

This was mainly included in this write-up so that no one tries to reinvent what is already written.

**The Diagnostic Aggregator**

[diagnostic_aggregator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diagnostic_aggregator) is a package for aggregating and analyzing diagnostics data.

Assuming that you have a working robotic system publishing raw diagnostic data to `/diagnostics`, you will see that the raw data accumulates quickly, and becomes cumbersome to actually sort through.  For this reason, we use the `diagnostic_aggregator`.  It allows us to group and sort data into namespaces (much like the ROS computational graph).  It will also rate-limit the aggregated diagnostics output to `~pub_rate` (typically 1 Hz).

From the wiki page, this can transform something like:

```
Left Wheel
Right Wheel
SICK Frequency
SICK Temperature
SICK Connection Status
Stereo Left Camera
Stereo Right Camera
Stereo Analysis
Stereo Connection Status
Battery 1 Level
Battery 2 Level
Battery 3 Level
Battery 4 Level
Voltage Status
```

Into something that is more readable, like:

```
My Robot/Wheels/Left
My Robot/Wheels/Right
My Robot/SICK/Frequency
My Robot/SICK/Temperature
My Robot/SICK/Connection Status
My Robot/Stereo/Left Camera
My Robot/Stereo/Right Camera
My Robot/Stereo/Analysis
My Robot/Stereo/Connection Status
My Robot/Power System/Battery 1 Level
My Robot/Power System/Battery 2 Level
My Robot/Power System/Battery 3 Level
My Robot/Power System/Battery 4 Level
My Robot/Power System/Voltage Status
```

Additionally, each group is given a `level`, which allows you to quickly see at-a-glance, where the errors are on your machine.  ERROR and WARN propagates up the tree.  For instance, an ERROR on `Left` propagates up to an ERROR on `Wheels`, and an `ERROR` on My Robot.

This can then be inspected using the [robot_monitor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_monitor) tool.

**Why Should I Use This**

Using `/diagnostics` is best practice on a robotic system of any scale.  It makes troubleshooting hardware (and software) easier in almost all cases.

Using `/diagnostics_agg` is good practice on any larger robotic system.  It is also good practice on any sort of production system, as it allows more flexibility and clarity when looking at diagnostics data.

Additionally, if the system is already set up to use aggregated diagnostics, the user may choose to write additional analyzer plugins for their system, further customizing diagnostic analysis.

**Helpful Resources**

- [diagnostics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diagnostics)
- [robot_monitor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_monitor)
- [runtime_monitor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/runtime_monitor)
- [microstrain_3dmgx2_imu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu) - A node that publishes good diagnostics data
- [pr2_analyzers.yaml](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/diagnostics/trunk/diagnostic_aggregator/demo/pr2_analyzers.yaml) - A good example of setting up analyzers for use with diagnostic_aggregator

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-10-31**:
RFP 107 might be worth being added to the ref to get an overview of ROS' diagnostics concept: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0107.html

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-07-02**:
This has been added to ROS/Patterns here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Patterns/RobotModelling#Runtime_Diagnostics